# Python Program to extract year part from a list of dates

Tags: list, python-2.7

This is the list of dates I have been asked to extract the year part from this list
['22-7-1997','1-12-1996','17-06-1992','10-09-1999']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datesList = ['17-12-1997','22-04-2011','01-05-1993','19-06-2020']
```

year = [x.split('-')[2] for x in datesList]
print('Years are: ',year)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using `datetime` module and a list comprehension:

```sh
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dates = ['22-7-1997','1-12-1996','17-06-1992','10-09-1999']
>>> [dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d-%m-%Y").year for date_string in dates]
[1997, 1996, 1992, 1999]
```